# Calculating rating gives "NaN"

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to calculate rating with values from Firebase. However the output is always `NaN` (“not a number”) whatever what those `ratersCount` and `rating` values are. What could cause this and how to fix it?

This is how I get values from Firebase:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Snuses").queryOrdered(byChild: "Brand").queryEqual(toValue: brandName)
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists(){

                let enumerator = snapshot.children

                while let thisProduct = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot
                {

                    // Chances are you'd have to create a dictionary
                    let thisProductDict = thisProduct.value as! [String:AnyObject]
                    let rating = thisProductDict["rating"] as! Double
                    let ratersCount = thisProductDict["ratersCount"] as! Double

                    let ratingToShow: Double = rating / ratersCount//Here I do the calculation
```

If I try to print out rating, ratersCount and the calculations, the output is:

```
0.0//rating
0.0//ratersCount
Rating is equal to nan
```

But I know the values are not even zero:

```
Snuses
 Catch Dry Eucalyptus White Mini
 ratersCount: 2
 rating: 5
```

Comment: If you are printing zero and you know the values shouldn't be zero, then the problem doesn't lie here. Maybe you are referencing a bad object or there is a problem in your database. We cannot know without seeing your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With floating point arithmetics (decimals) dividing by zero (which is an invalid operation) returns a special error value `NaN` (*Not a Number*).

The fix is very simple, you have to check for zero first:

```
// return zero if ratesCount is zero
let ratingToShow = (ratersCount == 0) ? 0 : rating / ratersCount
```

Note that if you had two integers there (e.g. `Int` type), the division would result in a crash.

A safer code would be to merge the check with check for `nil`:

```
let ratingToShow: Double

if let rating = thisProductDict["rating"] as? Double,
    let ratersCount = thisProductDict["ratersCount"] as? Double,
    ratersCount > 0 {

    ratingToShow = rating / ratersCount
} else {
   ratingToShow = 0
}
```

To prevent crash with invalid data if you are worried about that.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for that explanation. This is much better solution that I came up with :) And yep, that sometimes it says it is zero and it isn't, the problem is somewhere else.